# make Toast when ListView is empty

Tags: android, listview, toast

I want to reveal a **Toast** when my listview is empty, I tried this but it doesn't work, I don't understand why:

```
if (listView == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No slots selected",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I know how Toast work, but my problem is to detect when a listview is empty.

Could anyone help me plz ?

Comment: ListView is empty means adapter is empty which means data is null or empty. Check adapter size or data rather than `listview == null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the list that attached to your ListView (by the adapter).
When a List is created you can't check by `== null` because the variable is already created.

Instead checking the list size, something like this:

```
adapter.getCount() == 0
```

Comment: Ok it's cool, I didn't understand in this way, thank's a lot, it works with your method !

Comment: @simonvancoillie because List is a special case :), I have same mistake last time with List and ArrayList :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the size of the list you are attaching to ListView.

Lets say list is ArrayList attached to ListView

```
if(list.size()==0)
{
//Perform Action
}
```

Comment: Same for you mate, android "cannot resolve size()", but thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as well

```
if(list!=null && !list.isEmpty())
{
     //Show Listview
} else {
     //Show Toast (List Empty)
}
```

Comment: I tried it but  android studio "cannot resolve isEmpty", thanks for your answer, finally i succeed with "listView.getCount() == 0"

Comment: isEmpty() is used only for ArrayList..If you have String Array then you can use list.length>0.

Answer (score 0):

> **Instead of listview you should keep track of count for adapter attached to listView.**

**Try something like**

```
if(listViewAdapter.getItemCount.size()==0){
    // Toast Message
}else{
    // Populate your data
}
```

**OR**

> Instead of listview you should keep track of count for list attached to listView.

```
if(list.size()==0){
        // Toast Message
    }else{
        // Populate your data
    }
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer, I finally find the way, but i'll inform deeper on adapter, cause I don't know many things  (even nothing) about it

Answer (score 0):

```
if(listView.getCount() == 0 )
    Toast.makeText(dd.this, "The list is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```